# AWS API Gateway Pointing to DigitalOcean Domain

Tags: api-gateway

There is requirement we need to create a new AWS API Gateway but our Domain resits in the Digitalocean, So can we point the API gateway endpoint to the digitalocean domain. So the traffic should come to the domain and then API gateway.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes you can do that, you have to

- Request certificate
- Approve certificate (To prove your ownership of domain)
- Create custom domain for API Gateway
- Add base-path mapping (Attach to respective API endpoint)

Please follow below detailed link
https://medium.com/@maciejtreder/custom-domain-in-aws-api-gateway-a2b7feaf9c74